# A strange ssl error on android: SSL handshake aborted,Connection reset by peer

Tags: android, ssl, https, handshake

The error happens sometimes, the error state may last for a while, and after that it will recover automatically.

the exception as below:
[image]

SSL handshakes failed,it seems that the server reset the connection,then I captured the packets at the sever end:
[image]

192.168.5.126 is server,192.168.111.216 is android client.we can see that client reset the connection first and then send "client hello" to server repeatedly, server reset the connection.

In the successfull case, packets as below:
[image]

So, why the client choose to reset the connection, what happens at that time?

1. Does the server not support TLS1? not exactly, sometimes OK.
2. Dose the network affected? always use wifi and can capture packets on the server end which indicates the network is ok.
3. Some bugs may exist in the implementation of HTTPS? we use the org.apache.http package to connect HTTPS server.

Then I google it, but found no complete solution.

Has anybody encountered the problem like this, or anybody can help? thanks a lot!

Comment: anything in the server logs?

Comment: According to the trace the clients sees the server resetting the connection. But according to the packet capture the client is resetting the connection before the server does it. Are there any middleboxes (firewalls etc) involved?

Comment: @e4c5 found nothing abnormal in the server logs

Comment: @SteffenUllrich The android reset packet seems indicating that HTTS handshake aborting is not the behavior of SSL layer, if that, SSL layer should send back a packet including enough info of aborting reason instead of send a reset packet directly.So there could be some middleboxes involved, I will try to find, do you have any advice of how to? thanks

Comment: @teck_zhou: first it is only the theory that you should get a TLS alert on any TlS errors. In practice some stacks simply close or even reset the connection on errors. To check for middleboxes you should to a trace at the client and at the server and then check if there are differences like packets which can only be seen on one site and thus either don't pass through the middlebox or where created by the middlebox.